# SyntaxError: Unexpected token. async/await node 8

Tags: javascript, node.js

trying to use `async/await` with express. But getting error

```
const getData = async () => {
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
```

Node version - 8.5.0

**Part of code**

```
const getData = async () => {
  return 'all done';
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: yes i'm sure 
Only one place where is this code used

Comment: Looks like you would want to not use the word async unless you are calling the async to do `async.each(...);` for example. Docs:https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

Comment: not using `async` lib 
this is native async/await 
> Node.js 7.6 has shipped with official support for async/await enabled by default.

Comment: Checked on my env, works totally fine =/ Node 8.4.0, is it a full example? Are you sure that you do not use NVM and current node version is less than 8?

Comment: @steppefox, i'm using NVM. made like this nvm install 8.5.0 and then nvm use 8.5.0.  => 
necromant1k@necromant1k:~/github/project$ nvm current =>
v8.5.0

Comment: @АндрейГузюк what about command `node -v`? In the same console tab where you run your code. i want to mention, that if you changed node version in separate tab, all other tabs won't see new node version, you'll need to run code in the new tab =/

Comment: @steppefox, ok just totally reinstalled nodejs and now it works. Thank you for help

Answer (score -2):

The solution to this problem appears to be a re-installation of Node.